# Is it possible to combine 2 requests in one query, while the second one is executed only if the first one doesn't bring anything?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Suppose we have a table DVDs:

```
id  title                   type    
 1  Star Wars               Movie
 2  Yellow Submarine        Music
 3  The Lord of The Rings   Movie
 4  Black Butterfly         Music
```

We want to get dvd with movie 'Black Butterfly', but if it's not exist in the list, then we want to get other film.
Firth request:

```
Select * from DVDs where type='Movie' and title='Black Butterfly'
```

If request returns nothing, then execute second request.

```
Select * from DVDs where type='Moview'
```

At the moment, I'm using(in Java) 2 query-templates and 2 requests to the database(Oracle). I'm looking for an opportunity to use 1 template and 1 request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
with b as (
      Select *
      from DVDs
      where type = 'Movie' and title = 'Black Butterfly'
     )
select b.*
from b
union all
select d.*
from dvd
where type = 'Movie' and not exists (select 1 from b);
```

Alternatively, you could use window functions:

```
Select . . .
from (select d.*,
             count(*) filter (where title = 'Black Butterfly') over () as cnt_bb
      from DVDs d
      where type = 'Movie'
     ) d 
where cnt_bb = 0 or title = 'Black Butterfly';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (Select * from DVDs where type='Movie' and title='Black Butterfly') THEN
    Select * from DVDs where type='Movie' and title='Black Butterfly';
ELSE 
   Select * from DVDs where type='Moview';
END IF;
END
$do$
```

Comment: ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement